# CSS 'contains' attribute selector not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I want to change the margins round images depending on how they are floated. I used the 'contains' attribute selector which works fine except for IE8. See code below.

I cant really alter the HTML (eg cant add a class to identify the element) (as it is generated by a WYSIWYG editor within Drupal).

Can anyone suggest an alternative I can use to target the "float:left"?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
img[style*="float"][style*="left"]
{
    margin: 40px;
    background: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="float:left" width="100" height="100">
</body>
</html>
```

(I also created a jsfiddle but its no good as jsFiddle seems to have problems with IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/spiderplant0/FAxmp/)

Comment: To open on IE8: http://fiddle.jshell.net/spiderplant0/FAxmp/show/light/

Comment: @RaphaelDDL, thanks. I see the bug using this link also. I take it you see the bug also with IE8?

Comment: Have just tested it in IE8 on windows XP (in VmWare) and bug exists there also.

Comment: Tried to use jQuery to select it, but this fails in IE8 also... http://fiddle.jshell.net/spiderplant0/KZGFD/show/light/

Comment: Spider, try what @GCyrillus said in the answer: "re edit it seems like it parses only values of style , not the rule.". Test with `img[style*=left]` only. Probably will work if what GC said was true. But then, if any image with no float but with `text-align:left;` for e.g. will be selected as well.

Comment: Thanks @RaphaelDDL. `img[style*="left"]` works and will be adequate for my needs

Comment: Awesome =) Thanks GCyrillus for finding that IE8 attribute selector just looks for values on 'style', not properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a polyfill, easy to implement if you already use a js framework :
http://selectivizr.com/
But there's others.
**edit:** as you tell, you are already using one.

> ie9.js

You should make sure that your style are in an external file and apparently not linked via `@import` in order to see polyfills efficient.
Cheers

**re edit** it seems like it parses only values of style, not the rule.

Therefore, the following selector will work on IE8:

```
img[style*=left] {
    /* css */
}
```

Comment: Nope - all attribute selectors are supported in IE8 - in fact after testing locally it seems to be working fine ..

Comment: @CGyrillus, I am already using ie9.js to improve IE8. Maybe selectivizr.com is better though.

Comment: @Adrift. Are you saying that it works for you with IE8? Thats strange. I am using IE8 emulation mode in IE10 on windows 7 64 bit. Which version of IE are you using please?

Comment: @Adrift, thanks. How about RaphaelIDDLs link... http://fiddle.jshell.net/spiderplant0/FAxmp/show/light/

Comment: @Adrift, in a real IE8 it doesn't work . http://liveweave.com/GIOCxJ test it like i did with an IE8 stand alone (xp for my virtual machine) and find out what happens.

Comment: @spiderplant0 , in order to be efficient, i believe that style sheet must be in external file to be parsed by polyfills. CSS in head style or inline attributes won't be seen .

Comment: @GCyrillus, thanks. In the actual project the styles are in an external file.

Comment: @GCyrillus, no it is using the <link>

Comment: I understand that [attr*="value"] should be supported by IE8 (its IE7 that doesnt have it). But mayebe its not implemented by IE8 very well.

Comment: i made a test with mootools+selectivizir and i guess the bug is that it only gets values of style : ex: float:left;display:inline; you can check on left or inline, float and display are swaped. test : http://doc-css.com/ie8/ie8&selector.html

Comment: thanks @GCyrillus, I didnt initially understand what you meant, but simplifying the selector works with IE8. `img[style*="left"]`

Comment: glad for you, excuse my average english. :)